# Synch a phone to Linux PC without Google

Tags: applications, sync, linux

Is there a way to **synch** the SMS/Calendar/Contacts/what not (I am not talking about files, and pictures, etc.) to a **Linux** (Ubuntu) PC? The quirk is to **bypass Google** in the process.So I would envision an App running on the phone sending all data to the PC in, say CSV or something like that... Can you advise?

Comment: Sure there is – at least for contacts/calendars (keywords: CardDAV/CalDAV). You might be interested in reading my *Android without Google* blog series, especially: [Android without Google 2: ownCloud](https://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android-without-google-2).

Comment: @Izzy
That makes a lot of sense! Thank you. (I think you should expand your comment into an answer.)

Comment: Why the heck did this question get down-voted?

Comment: I don't know. I just wonder why my answer didn't get upvoted – especially as you explicitly asked me to post it ;)

Comment: can anyone add something about integration with thunderbird?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, at least for calendars and contacts:

- On Windows: Check out [MyPhoneExplorer](http://www.fjsoft.at/). Offers a lot of additional features like Backup Assistant, file browser, managing calls – and also syncs SMS.
- Using a CalDAV/CardDAV server of your choice, such as [Baïkal](https://github.com/fruux/Baikal) or [ownCloud](https://owncloud.org/). I use the latter – so for details, take a look at my article [Android without Google 2: ownCloud](https://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android-without-google-2). This would be independent of the OS on your computer, but you will need a web server. Big advantage: You can access your data from anywhere you've got a web browser working. And with *ownCloud* this also can include your documents, photo galleries, and more.